# How do I modify gnome-shell configuration files in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, gnome, ubuntu-gnome

In Ubuntu GNOME 14.04 it was possible to do a lot of tweaking on gnome-shell through the .js files. These files appear to have been wrapped up since Gnome 3.12, as explained here:

[Keeping gnome shell approachable](https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/03/24/keeping-gnome-shell-approachable)

A more recent post details the updated procedure to extract the .js files and test the modifications:

[How do I extract shell](https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/ExtractShell)

However, these posts do not explain how to make the changes permanent.

I tried to recompile the original file using the command `glib-compile-resources resources.gresource.xml` but managed only to break gnome-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no middle way to permanently implement modifications made on the JavaScript files and it is necessary to build the whole gnome-shell package again, as explained in this thread:

[Gnome-shell list 2016 October](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gnome-shell-list/2016-October/msg00001.html)

Or wait for an extension to make tweaking of the application overview easy.

NOTE: It is possible to make some tweaking without re-compiling gnome-shell, by editing `/usr/lib/gnome-shell/libgnome-shell.so` in a hex editor. For instance, you can change the number of columns and/or rows in the application overview by doing the following:

- Make a backup of `libgnome-shell.so` in case something goes wrong.
- Open `libgnome-shell.so` with an hex editor (I used Bless) and search for `MAX_COLUMNS = 6` as text.
- Replace `6` with ascii value of the number of columns that you want. If you want a 2-digit value, you will need to delete the space between the `=` equal sign and the original `6`, like in `MAX_COLUMNS =10`.
- You can do the same for the number of rows by changing `MIN_ROWS`, and for the icon size by changing `ICON_SIZE` (search for `const ICON_SIZE`).
- Save and replace `libgnome-shell.so`.
- Restart gnome-shell (press Alt+F2 and in the popup enter 'r' or 'restart' and press enter).

Many thanks to [VoOoLoX](https://askubuntu.com/users/691400/vooolox) for suggesting this procedure in a [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822281/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-columns-in-the-application-overview-in-gnome-3-18).