# How to Increase the number of columns in application overview(using some extension) and change it's animation

Tags: gnome, 18.04, unity-dash, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

[image: Desktop Image]

Please refer attached image for clarity.

1)How can I increase the number of columns in the show application? I want to Increase it to 7 or 8. I l[this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/822281/how-do-i-change-the-number-of-columns-in-the-application-overview-in-gnome-3-18) This works but is there some extension to available to do this? [Answered Here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/)

2) Also, I don't really like the animation with which the icons load up after I click on show applications button is there any way to change it and make it cleaner probably the animation used in windows 8 for start button.

Comment: How did you get your show application button to be on the left side?

Comment: gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-apps-at-top true

Comment: or use `dconf-editor` and set this to true `org > gnome > shell > extensions > dash-to-dock`

Comment: There was question here with someone asking for this, OMG!

Comment: yeah and the thing actually works, I made the columns to 8. I was hoping to find some extension that does it for me or something simpler.

Comment: And how did that happen, that should be a knowledge question and your answer following

Comment: just follow the accepted answer it works in 18.4 as well.

Comment: @pomsky, not a duplicate Edited the question also I want to change the animation.

Comment: @Kid101 Yes, and my answer suggests this extension (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/)?! I don't get your point. Did you even check the suggested Q&A? And please ask a separate question for the animation part. They seem unrelated (and such a question usually gets closed as "too-broad"). Or just simply refer to [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067760/faster-app-menu-in-ubuntu-18-04).

Comment: I'll ask animation in different question @pomsky

Comment: @pomsky asked here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068409/change-animation-of-show-application. Also I've already made an edit to the question pointing to your answer

Comment: Just consider hitting the "this solves my problem" button/.