# Change animation of show application.

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

[image]

I don't really like the animation with which the icons load up after I click on show applications button is there any way to change it and make it cleaner probably the animation used in windows 8 for start button.

Comment: @pomsky I want to change it like windows 8 not disable it altogether

Comment: Then you'll have to explain explicitly what do you mean by "change it like windows 8", many people won't be aware of what that means. If you follow the first suggestion in my answer, you'll get a simple fade-in/fade-out effect instead of the "icons flying-in from the *Show Applications*" button effect.

Comment: @pomsky I'll search for that windows 8 animation and update. disabling the animation to get simple fade-in/fade-out doesn't look neat